# Подключение статичных библиотек SFML (Network - если быть точным)

Tags: c++, сеть, tcp, sfml, lib

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: я работаю в VS19 и использую библиотеки SFML для работы, до этого я ни разу не работал со статичными библиотеками, так что, не то, что бы разбираюсь в них.

> Автор, добавьте уточнение, пожалуйста, что это вариант подключения по умолчанию, с динамической линковкой. В дальнейшем, для запуска приложения не в студии, а с экзешника, потребуется все файлы из папки bin класть в одну директорию с ним. Для упрощения, можно использовать статическую линковку: к вышеописанному руководству, добавляем в настройках проекта C/C++ ->Preprocessor ->Preprocessor Definitions пишем SFML_STATIC; (Для всех конфигураций). В компоновщике, где прописывали зависимости, для каждого режима (!!!) отдельно — Debug и Release, копипастим следующее:

```
Для релиза :

sfml-graphics-s.lib
sfml-window-s.lib
sfml-system-s.lib
sfml-audio-s.lib
opengl32.lib
winmm.lib
gdi32.lib
freetype.lib
openal32.lib
flac.lib
vorbisenc.lib
vorbisfile.lib
vorbis.lib
ogg.lib

Для дебага:

sfml-graphics-s-d.lib
sfml-window-s-d.lib
sfml-system-s-d.lib
sfml-audio-s-d.lib
opengl32.lib
winmm.lib
gdi32.lib
freetype.lib
openal32.lib
flac.lib
vorbisenc.lib
vorbisfile.lib
vorbis.lib
ogg.lib
```

> Всё будет сжато в единый , без сбоев при запуске на других компах.

[Статья откуда этот комментарий.](https://ravesli.com/graficheskaya-biblioteka-sfml-vstuplenie-i-ustanovka/)

Использовал этот совет, чтобы сделать полноценный exe файл без необходимости в оставшейся части в виде десятка dll. Я провел некоторые тесты с использование подобных конструкций:

```
 #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
 int main() {sf::Window w();
 return 0; }
```

Все прекрасно работало на релиз версии, как у меня, так и на другой машине. Единственное, я больше не экспериментировал, вероятно, в дальнейшем у меня бы возникла эта ошибка в любом случае, но так как она обнаружилась тут, я на эти строки и грешу:

#### Элемент кода:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main(){using namespace std;
using namespace sf;
sf::TcpSocket socket;
return 0;}
```

#### Ошибка:

[image: Ошибка библиотек при загрузке вышеуказанного кода]

#### Настройки:

[image: Библиотеки Debug режима][image: Библиотеки Release режима][image: Препроцессор - все версии][image: Компоновщик - все версии]

Также я решил поиграть в "дурачка" и каждой версии по очереди добавлял библиотеки с придуманным названием , схожим с тем, как называются другие из той же библиотеки, по типу: sfml-network-2-d.lib и т.д.
 Понятное дело, это не помогло.
Исходя из всего, написанного выше, я понимаю, что сам вряд ли смогу разобраться.
Поэтому прошу помочь с этим вопросом.
 Заранее спасибо. И спасибо, что уделили этому вопросу время :)

[image: Использовал названия библиотек, как в указано в комментариях(+названия, указанные в самой библиотеке sfml - ошибка не меняется)]

Comment: ¿Почему бы просто не посмотреть, как именно называется файл с network либой?

Comment: sfml-network-s.lib, sfml-network-s-d.lib

Comment: @user7860670 Да, я понимаю, я указал, что пробовал(вариант «дурачка»),но это не исправило ошибку

Comment: @mik.ov , спасибо. Я попробовал, но ошибку такую уже получал, я ее добавил(картинку), чтобы вы могли посмотреть

Comment: добавить ещё `#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")` желательно

Comment: @KoVadim , огромное спасибо. Уж не знаю почему, но именно этого не хватало в коде, сейчас все функционирует. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

столкнулся схожей проблемой, в общем если говорить кратко то в плане зависимостей дела обстоят следующим образом:

```
Делается это все под Debug x64

sfml-network-d.lib
sfml-graphics-d.lib
sfml-window-d.lib
sfml-system-d.lib
sfml-audio-d.lib
kernel32.lib
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
winspool.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
odbc32.lib
odbccp32.lib
```

ссылка на папки include и lib оставляем без изменений.
 Также помимо этого в настройка проекта нужно указать препроцессор. В большинстве мануалов по установке SFML, предлагают выставить **SFML_STATIC**, но у меня выставлен **SFML_DYNAMIC**
[image: препроцессор]

Далее что не мало важно нужно зайти в папку где хранится сама SFML, зайти в папку **bin**, и скопировать оттуда выделенные файлы, и перекинуть в папку где находится исходники проекта
[image: те самые файлы]

В качестве тестового примера для проверки работоспособности использовал ниже приведенный код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <string>
    
using namespace std;
    
static bool port_is_open(const string& address, int port)
{
   return (sf::TcpSocket().connect(address, port) == sf::Socket::Done);
}
    
int main()
{
cout << "Port 443 : ";
if (port_is_open("stackoverflow.com", 443)) {
    cout << "OPEN" << endl;
     system("PAUSE");
}
            
else
   cout << "CLOSED" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

[image: результат теста]

Чуть не забыл, данный метод работает не только с sfml-network, но и с другими компонентами, то есть: sfml-audio, sfml-graphics, и т.д.

Comment: Вы все хорошо расписали, но вот только в вопросе автор спрашивал о статической линковке, а Вы привели динамическую.  `В большинстве мануалов по установке SFML, предлагают выставить SFML_STATIC` - конечно просят, если нужна статическая линковка.

Answer (score 0):

1. Прописать в предпроцессор макрос `SFML_STATIC`
2. Прописать статические библиотеки ("sfml-xxx-s.lib" для релиза или "sfml-xxx-s-d.lib" для дебага)
3. Прописать нужные зависимости см. [оф.сайт](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php):

   [image: таблица зависимостей]

Список всех библиотек для Release x64:

```
sfml-system-s.lib
winmm.lib

sfml-window-s.lib
opengl32.lib
gdi32.lib

sfml-graphics-s.lib
freetype.lib

sfml-audio-s.lib
flac.lib
vorbisenc.lib
vorbisfile.lib
vorbis.lib
ogg.lib

sfml-network-s.lib
ws2_32.lib
```

Уже прописанные зависимости нарочно опущены. Так, например, для sfml-window необходима sfml-system, которая уже прописана, значит не обязательно прописывать ее еще раз.